# wraps works but doesn't redirect to login when html page is entered

Tags: python, session, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, functools

I have created a login page with `wraps` & `functools`.  I have done this previously and it worked, but this time I have stored the username & password in a PostgreSQL database and queried it using the sqlalchemy flask extension.

If the correct details have been entered, it logs you into the admin page, but if you try to type on the admin page, it doesn't redirect you back to the login page.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, request, redirect, flash, session
from functools import wraps

app = Flask(__name__)

app.secret_key = "pythonAkoto"

def login_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        if 'logged_in' in session:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            flash('You need to sign in first')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return wrap

from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship

# # this part is needed to create session to query database. this should be JUST BELOW app.config..

from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Table, Column, Integer, String, ForeignKey, select
meta = MetaData()
engine = create_engine("postgresql://postgres:password@localhost/db_name", echo = True)
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()

# posts database
class PostTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'poststable'
    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    user = Column('username', String(20))
    posts = Column('posts', String(30))

    def __init__(self, user, posts):
        self.user = user
        self.posts = posts

# login database
class UserLogin(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user_login'
    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = Column('username', String(30))
    userPW = Column('user_pw', String(20))

    def __init__(self, username, user_pw):
        self.username = username
        self.user_pw = user_pw

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
db_session = Session() # i have called this db_session to not get mixed up with sessions when logging in.

# write posts on wall
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def postpage():
    title = "Posts"
        name = request.form.get('name')
        posts = request.form.get('posts')
        if request.method == 'GET':
        data = db_session.query(PostsTable).all()
        flash('Write something on the wall!')
        return render_template("postpage.html", title=title, data=data)
    else:
        db_entry = PostsTable(name, posts)
        db_session.add(db_entry)
        db_session.commit()
        data = db_session.query(PostsTable).all()
        flash(f'{name} just wrote a post!')
        return render_template("postpage.html", data=data, title=title)

# login into admin page
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    title = "Login"
    user = request.form.get("username")
    upw = request.form.get("password")
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template("login.html", title=title)
    else:
        db_user = db_session.query(UserLogin).filter(UserLogin.username==f'{user}')
        db_pw = db_session.query(UserLogin).filter(UserLogin.userPW==f'{upw}')
        result = db_user.first() and db_pw.first()

        if result:
            session['logged_in'] = True
            flash(f'Hey {user}, you have just logged in!')
            return redirect(url_for('admin'))
        else:
             error = "Invalid credentials.  Please enter a valid username and/or password."
    return render_template('login.html', error=error, title=title)

# admin page
@app.route('/admin')
@login_required
def admin():
    title = "Admin"
    return render_template("admin.html", title=title)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When you enter admin url, it's supposed to redirect you to the login page, but this doesn't happen; instead it takes you to the admin page without logging in!

I've done this before (without the database) and it worked fine, but this way isn't working and I can't seem to understand why.

Comment: You mention you're [using `flask-sqlalchemy`](https://github.com/pallets/flask-sqlalchemy) but all I see in your code is using `sqlalchemy` directly.  I'd suggest [checking out this tutorial](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/views/) on Blueprints to make a login wrapper.

Comment: Thanks I'm gonna watch a video on Blueprints now and get back to you... yes, that was my error its definitely sqlalchemy i'm using